# Is it possible to send API request via HTTP2 using .Net Framework 4.5?

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient, http2

I need to force our API to send requests to another third-party API via HTTP2, but updating the .Net Framework version is not an option. Our API is currently using .Net Framework 4.5. Is this possible or not? I tried using `WinHttpHandler`, but it is not compatible with .Net Framework 4.5 therefore could not install it at all. I also tried the following code below, but it throws exception "Only HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 version requests are currently supported" on `SendAsync()`. I'm using latest System.Net.Http 4.3.4. Anyone knows any other way?

```
HttpRequestMessage requestMsg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, apiURL);
**requestMsg.Version = new Version(2, 0);**
requestMsg.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage result = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMsg);
string response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: `updating the .Net Framework version is not an option` quite the opposite - most likely it's already updated, since most supported Windows versions come with newer versions. Even 4.6.1 is [reaching End-of-Life by April 2022](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-framework-4-5-2-4-6-4-6-1-will-reach-end-of-support-on-april-26-2022/) (not just end-of-support) , so you'll *have* to upgrade to .NET 4.6.2 at least

Comment: Furthermore, only .NET 4.6 supports TLS1.2 by default, which is required by almost every service at this point. HTTP/2 *requires* TLS 1.2, and that means that almost all sites that support HTTP/2 (like ASP.NET Core sites) will probably require TLS1.2 as well

Comment: Unless there is a 3rd party HTTP/2 client library with sufficient support you're going to have to reconsider your .NET version or the HTTP/2 requirement. (For the latter could you use a proxy?)

Comment: .NET Core 3.0 was the first version with HTTP/2 client support: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#http2-support

Comment: Without reinventing HTTP client that's not possible. Use .NET Core 3.1 or newer .NET. You can also visit **dotnet/runtime** Github and copy-paste `SocketsHttpHandler`'s code from there.